# Getting the Redirected URL from the Original URL

Tags: c#, .net

I have a table in my database which contains the URLs of some websites. I have to open those URLs and verify some links on those pages. The problem is that some URLs get redirected to other URLs. My logic is failing for such URLs.

Is there some way through which I can pass my original URL string and get the redirected URL back?

Example: I am trying with this URL:
http://individual.troweprice.com/public/Retail/xStaticFiles/FormsAndLiterature/CollegeSavings/trp529Disclosure.pdf

It gets redirected to this one:
http://individual.troweprice.com/staticFiles/Retail/Shared/PDFs/trp529Disclosure.pdf

I tried to use following code:

```
HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(Uris);
req.Proxy = proxy;
req.Method = "HEAD";
req.AllowAutoRedirect = false;

HttpWebResponse myResp = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse();
if (myResp.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.Redirect)
{
  MessageBox.Show("redirected to:" + myResp.GetResponseHeader("Location"));
}
```

When I execute the code above it gives me `HttpStatusCodeOk`. I am surprised why it is not considering it a redirection. If I open the link in Internet Explorer then it will redirect to another URL and open the PDF file.

Can someone help me understand why it is not working properly for the example URL?

By the way, I checked with Hotmail's URL (http://www.hotmail.com) and it correctly returns the redirected URL.

Answer (score 31):

This function will return the final destination of a link — even if there are multiple redirects. It doesn't account for JavaScript-based redirects or META redirects. Notice that the previous solution didn't deal with Absolute & Relative URLs, since the LOCATION header could return something like "/newhome" you need to combine with the URL that served that response to identify the full URL destination.

```
    public static string GetFinalRedirect(string url)
    {
        if(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(url))
            return url;

        int maxRedirCount = 8;  // prevent infinite loops
        string newUrl = url;
        do
        {
            HttpWebRequest req = null;
            HttpWebResponse resp = null;
            try
            {
                req = (HttpWebRequest) HttpWebRequest.Create(url);
                req.Method = "HEAD";
                req.AllowAutoRedirect = false;
                resp = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse();
                switch (resp.StatusCode)
                {
                    case HttpStatusCode.OK:
                        return newUrl;
                    case HttpStatusCode.Redirect:
                    case HttpStatusCode.MovedPermanently:
                    case HttpStatusCode.RedirectKeepVerb:
                    case HttpStatusCode.RedirectMethod:
                        newUrl = resp.Headers["Location"];
                        if (newUrl == null)
                            return url;

                        if (newUrl.IndexOf("://", System.StringComparison.Ordinal) == -1)
                        {
                            // Doesn't have a URL Schema, meaning it's a relative or absolute URL
                            Uri u = new Uri(new Uri(url), newUrl);
                            newUrl = u.ToString();
                        }
                        break;
                    default:
                        return newUrl;
                }
                url = newUrl;
            }
            catch (WebException)
            {
                // Return the last known good URL
                return newUrl;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return null;
            }
            finally
            {
                if (resp != null)
                    resp.Close();
            }
        } while (maxRedirCount-- > 0);

        return newUrl;
    }
```

Comment: I took http://feeds.gawker.com/lifehacker/full as an example.  Chrome dev tools shows a 307 redirect and the location header set to https://feeds.feedburner.com/lifehacker/full.  But when I use your code above I'm always getting a 200 OK.  Any ideas?

Comment: @Howiecamp Very likely they are sending different responses based on User-Agent. You can change the req.UserAgent to look like a Chrome browser.

Answer (score 22):

The URL you mentioned uses a JavaScript redirect, which will only redirect a browser. So there's no easy way to detect the redirect.

For proper (HTTP Status Code and Location:) redirects, you might want to remove

```
req.AllowAutoRedirect = false;
```

and get the final URL using

```
myResp.ResponseUri
```

as there can be more than one redirect.

**UPDATE: More clarification regarding redirects:**

There's more than one way to redirect a browser to another URL.

The first way is to use a 3xx HTTP status code, and the Location: header. This is the way the gods intended HTTP redirects to work, and is also known as "the one true way." This method will work on all browsers and crawlers.

And then there are the devil's ways. These include [meta refresh](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meta_refresh), the Refresh: header, and JavaScript. Although these methods work in most browsers, they are definitely not guaranteed to work, and occasionally result in strange behavior (aka. [breaking the back button](http://www.w3.org/QA/Tips/reback)).

Most web crawlers, including the Googlebot, ignore these redirection methods, and so should you. If you absolutely *have* to detect all redirects, then you would have to parse the HTML for META tags, look for Refresh: headers in the response, and evaluate Javascript. Good luck with the last one.

Comment: Removing req.AllowAutoRedirect = false; doesn't help

Comment: I understand your point of javascript redirect, but when i use myResp.ResponseUri.AbsoluteUri it gives me the original URL instead of redirected one.

So is there any other way to get the redirected URL?

Comment: The URL in question will always return the same URL, because it doesn't redirect. The *apparent* redirection is only Javascript, and you would have to evaluate Javascript to detect it.

Comment: Okay...how can I evaluate Javascript to get the redirected URL? Can you provide some code to do this?

Comment: Does not work with http://www.google.com ? I expect to get ResponseUri is https://www.google.com but not !!!

Comment: Let's say you go to test1.com and test1.com goes to a page that has a javascript redirect to test2.com. If that's the case then you can view the source code of the page test1.com and extract the test2.com redirect domain directly from the source.

Answer (score 10):

Use this code to get redirecting URL

```
public void GrtUrl(string url)
{
    HttpWebRequest webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
    webRequest.AllowAutoRedirect = false;  // IMPORTANT

    webRequest.Timeout = 10000;           // timeout 10s
    webRequest.Method = "HEAD";
    // Get the response ...
    HttpWebResponse webResponse;
    using (webResponse = (HttpWebResponse)webRequest.GetResponse())
    {
        // Now look to see if it's a redirect
        if ((int)webResponse.StatusCode >= 300 && 
            (int)webResponse.StatusCode <= 399)
        {
            string uriString = webResponse.Headers["Location"];
            Console.WriteLine("Redirect to " + uriString ?? "NULL");
            webResponse.Close(); // don't forget to close it - or bad things happen
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Here's two Async `HttpClient` versions:

#### Works in .Net Framework and .Net Core

```cs
public static async Task<Uri> GetRedirectedUrlAsync(Uri uri, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
{
    using var client = new HttpClient(new HttpClientHandler
    {
        AllowAutoRedirect = false,
    }, true);
    using var response = await client.GetAsync(uri, cancellationToken);

    return new Uri(response.Headers.GetValues("Location").First();
}
```

#### Works in .Net Core

```cs
public static async Task<Uri> GetRedirectedUrlAsync(Uri uri, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
{
    using var client = new HttpClient();
    using var response = await client.GetAsync(uri, cancellationToken);

    return response.RequestMessage.RequestUri;
}
```

P.S. `handler.MaxAutomaticRedirections = 1` can be used if you need to limit the number of attempts.

Answer (score 2):

After reviewing everyone's suggestions I kind of figured this out for at least my case which basically did 3 loops once to https and second one to actual ending location.
This is a recursive function call here:

```
public static string GrtUrl(string url, int counter)
{
    ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls
    | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11
    | SecurityProtocolType.Tls12
    | SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3;
    string ReturnURL = url;
    HttpWebRequest webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
    webRequest.AllowAutoRedirect = false;  // IMPORTANT

    webRequest.Timeout = 10000;           // timeout 10s
    webRequest.Method = "HEAD";
    // Get the response ...
    HttpWebResponse webResponse;
    using (webResponse = (HttpWebResponse)webRequest.GetResponse())
    {
        // Now look to see if it's a redirect
        if ((int)webResponse.StatusCode >= 300 && (int)webResponse.StatusCode <= 399)
        {
            string uriString = webResponse.Headers["Location"];
            ReturnURL = uriString;
            if (ReturnURL == url)

            {
                webResponse.Close(); // don't forget to close it - or bad things happen!
                return ReturnURL;

            }
            else
            {
                webResponse.Close(); // don't forget to close it - or bad things happen!
                if (counter > 50)
                    return ReturnURL;
                else
                    return GrtUrl(ReturnURL, counter++);
            }

            
        }

    }
    return ReturnURL; 

}
```

Comment: Good answer. I use part of your code. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could check the Request.UrlReferrer.AbsoluteUri to see where i came from. If that doesn't work can you pass the old url as a query string parameter?

Comment: When I debug the code req.Referer is null and myResp.ResponseUri.AbsoluteUri returns the original URL instead of redirected URL.

I couldn't find UrlReferrer method available with Request object.

Answer (score 0):

This code works for me

```
var request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(url);
request.Method = "POST";
request.AllowAutoRedirect = true;
request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
var response = request.GetResponse();
```

//After sending the request and the request is expected to redirect to some page of your website, The response.ResponseUri.AbsoluteUri contains that url including the query strings 
//(www.yourwebsite.com/returnulr?r=""... and so on)

```
Redirect(response.ResponseUri.AbsoluteUri); //then just do your own redirect.
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and after tryin a lot I couldn't get what i wanted with HttpWebRequest so i used web browser class to navigate to first url and then i could get the redirected url !

```
WebBrowser browser = new WebBrowser();
browser.Navigating += new System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowserNavigatingEventHandler(this.browser_Navigating);
string urlToNavigate = "your url";
browser.Navigate(new Uri(urlToNavigate));
```

then on navigating you can get your redirected url. Be careful that the first time browser_Navigating event handler occurs, e.url is the same url you used to start browsing so you can get redirected url on the second call

```
private void browser_Navigating(object sender, WebBrowserNavigatingEventArgs e)
{
    Uri uri = e.Url;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This code worked for me with Unicode support:

```
 public static string GetFinalRedirect(string url)
    {
        try
        {
            var request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(url);
            request.Method = "POST";
            request.AllowAutoRedirect = true;
            request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
            var response = request.GetResponse();
            return response.ResponseUri.AbsoluteUri.ToString();
        }
        catch(Exception ax)
        {
            return "";
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

```
string url = ".......";
var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

string redirectUrl = response.ResponseUri.ToString();
```

Comment: Add some explanations

Answer (score -1):

A way to deal with javascript redirect is to view the source code of the initial domain's page that would load and then extract a new domain aka the final domain directly from the source code. Since it is a javascript redirect then the new domain aka final domain should be there. Cheers

Code to extract the URL address from page source:

```
string href = "";
string pageSrc = "get page source using web client download string method and place output here";
Match m = Regex.Match(pageSrc, @"href=\""(.*?)\""", RegexOptions.Singleline);
if (m2.Success){
    href = m.Groups[1].Value; /* will result in http://finalurl.com */
}
```

Answer (score -2):

I made this method using your code and it returns the final redirected URL.

```
        public string GetFinalRedirectedUrl(string url)
    {
        string result = string.Empty;

        Uri Uris = new Uri(url);

        HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(Uris);
        //req3.Proxy = proxy;
        req.Method = "HEAD";
        req.AllowAutoRedirect = false;

        HttpWebResponse myResp = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse();
        if (myResp.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.Redirect)
        {
            string temp = myResp.GetResponseHeader("Location");
            //Recursive call
            result = GetFinalRedirectedUrl(temp);
        }
        else
        {
            result = url;
        }

        return result;
    }
```

Note: myResp.ResponseUri does not return the final URL