# Get final redirect URL

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, httpwebrequest, httpwebresponse

I am writing a code to get through authentication to a API based web site. I have the API key that the site needs during the login process. When I call the login method with the API key, it is supposed to redirect to a predefined URL whose parameter will then contain the request token.

e.g on firing the URL in the browser,
https://kite.trade/connect/login?api_key=hcwmefsivttbchla

I am redirected to

https://impacted-purposes.000webhostapp.com/?status=success&request_token=nb0vrfota9ott1r02q153pk3422joruf
(The request token will change in every run)

Notice the request token in the URL on the redirected URL. That's what I need to get from the code.

So, I use a the code that is referred here `GetFinalRedirect`:
[Getting the Redirected URL from the Original URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/704956/getting-the-redirected-url-from-the-original-url)

ie. I call:

```
GetFinalRedirect("https://kite.trade/connect/login?api_key=hcwmefsivttbchla")
```

However, I don't get the final redirect. I understand there could be a Javascript redirect, but checking the response, doesn't suggest so.

Any help pls to get the final URL so that I can parse the request token from it.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I can't test this since i don't have an account. And I hope thats not your real-api-key...

But the function you're using is just sending a HEAD request to server. A HEAD request has no response. With the HEAD request you will only get redirects that are included in the HTTP headers. If the redirect is done with HTML-META tags or with javascript you have to send a GET (or POST) request...

If that fails too set a breakpoint inside the function and look at the received http-headers and the response text...

Comment: Thanks. Yes, it is the real API key and is safe to be posted here since there is 2nd step authentication expecting other keys (in particular a secret key) that is out of scope of the current problem. You may check it with this. I had changed the header to GET earlier, got the actual page, checked the meta tags and any JS redirects, couldn't find any. Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: @Kallol I'm sorry, but I see no way to check this. If I open the first link you posted (kite.trade) a login form is shown and I don't have an account to login and check how the redirect works...

Comment: @Kallol Have you set `.AllowAutoRedirect` to `false`? https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.allowautoredirect(v=vs.110).aspx