# How to get code parameter after redirecting url in c# business central?

Tags: c#, oauth-2.0, authorization, microsoft-dynamics

I need get the code that sends me after login correct (login.microsoft) with redirect URI but I dont know how to do it.

When I access correctly,  the code is sent to me throught the redirect URI like this:

```
https://businesscentral.dynamics.com/OAuthLanding.htm?code=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXstate=&session_state
```

That URL happens when I click to the URL authorit, but i dont know how to do it in the application.
The code below doesn't show me the redirect URI

```
 var httpClient = new HttpClient();
      

 const string authority = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/XXXXXXXXX/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?response_type=code&state=&client_id=XXXXXXXXXXXXX&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fapi.businesscentral.dynamics.com%2F.default&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fbusinesscentral.dynamics.com%2FOAuthLanding.htm";


 var request = httpClient.GetAsync(authority).Result;

 Console.WriteLine(request);
```

How can I get the code Authorization after that? When I click the authority, browser send me to the URL redirect, but with my code I can't access to the redirect URL, Any help???

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Getting the Redirected URL from the Original URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/704956/getting-the-redirected-url-from-the-original-url)

Comment: No it doesnt work for me