# decrypting amazon product urls for web scraping

Tags: javascript, python, web-scraping, encryption

I am trying to web scrap below Amaozn product site
https://www.amazon.com/s?k=mobile+phones&i=electronics&rh=n%3A172282%2Cn%3A2811119011%2Cn%3A7072561011&dc&qid=1651136142&rnid=172282&ref=sr_nr_n_1

there are multiple products (mobile phones) and I tried to get URL for each detail. I was planning to use these URL to get in to product detail page and extract more product details like brand , color and etc.

but these URLs are encrypted. How can I decrypt them.

encrypted URL - '/gp/slredirect/picassoRedirect.html/ref=pa_sp_atf_electronics_sr_pg1_1?ie=UTF8&adId=A01898201VJQNGUGGMF0I&url=%2FBlack-Shark-Unlocked-Charging-Snapdragon%2Fdp%2FB09BQP1LG8%2Fref%3Dsr_1_1_sspa%3Fkeywords%3Dmobile%2Bphones%26qid%3D1651149741%26rnid%3D172282%26s%3Delectronics%26sr%3D1-1-spons%26psc%3D1&qualifier=1651149741&id=2383349385815381&widgetName=sp_atf'

product detail page ( expected decrypted result) -https://www.amazon.com/Black-Shark-Unlocked-Charging-Snapdragon/dp/B09BQP1LG8/ref=sr_1_1_sspa?keywords=mobile%2Bphones&qid=1651149351&rnid=172282&s=electronics&sr=1-1-spons&spLa=ZW5jcnlwdGVkUXVhbGlmaWVyPUExMDZKOURHVVhDWlZCJmVuY3J5cHRlZElkPUEwODA1OTQxMkdPOU5FWkg3SFpTQiZlbmNyeXB0ZWRBZElkPUEwMTg5ODIwMVZKUU5HVUdHTUYwSSZ3aWRnZXROYW1lPXNwX2F0ZiZhY3Rpb249Y2xpY2tSZWRpcmVjdCZkb05vdExvZ0NsaWNrPXRydWU&th=1

Comment: There's no encryption here.  I see some hexadecimal and some base64, but not encryption.  Scraping websites is an acquired skill; you will need more tools in your toolkit than an answer in a Stack Overflow question will provide.

Comment: You mean [URL-encoded](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp) rather than encrypted.

Comment: Note that the only part of that second URL you need is `https://www.amazon.com/Black-Shark-Unlocked-Charging-Snapdragon/dp/B09BQP1LG8`.

Answer (score 2):

The "encrypted" url is actually a redirect, from a sponsored product/ad.
It is, in fact, *encoded.* However, the information is still there.

Either you can:

1. Get the information from the redirect url (it's in there, just a little deeper.)
2. Fetch the destination url. You can see more from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28424940/16261014).

Good luck!

Comment: @RobertHarvey Sorry, I meant encoded. Fixing that now.